# Sorting ITextSharp RenderListener Output

Tags: sorting, pdf, itext

I was able to successfully to get pictures and text using Render Listener. However, there are not in the order I want it to be. I tried ordering it by the rectangle class. (Top, Right, Bottom, Left). Nothing worked. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried and also elaborate on why it didn't work?

Comment: *there are not in the order I want it to be* - maybe you should start by explaining in which order you *do* want them to be...

Comment: Would the solution outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28087521/1729265) for iText be ok for you?

Comment: @mkl As of now I stopped trying to sort it out.