# read images from scanned documents PDFs

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using itextsharp for extracting content from PDF using c# as follow

```
  public static string GetTextFromAllPages(String pdfPath)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);

            StringWriter output = new StringWriter();

            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                output.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy()));


            return output.ToString();
        }
```

Now change I want in this code whenever there are images in PDF it should include an image tag (`<img>`) in the content.

I tried with the extracting images alone and I am able to do it but not sure how to merge these two codes together to make extracted content consist with img tag also .

Extraction code of image as follow :

```
private static List<System.Drawing.Image> ExtractImages(String PDFSourcePath)
        {

            //string res = GetTextFromAllPages(PDFSourcePath);
            //File.WriteAllText(@"d:\blobfile\blobfileresult.txt", res);
            List<System.Drawing.Image> ImgList = new List<System.Drawing.Image>();

            iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray RAFObj = null;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader PDFReaderObj = null;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject PDFObj = null;
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream PDFStremObj = null;

            try
            {
                RAFObj = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray(PDFSourcePath);
                PDFReaderObj = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(RAFObj, null);
                if (PDFReaderObj.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("this is a test");
                }

                for (int i = 0; i <= PDFReaderObj.XrefSize - 1; i++)
                {
                    PDFObj = PDFReaderObj.GetPdfObject(i);

                    if ((PDFObj != null) && PDFObj.IsStream())
                    {
                        PDFStremObj = (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStream)PDFObj;
                        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfObject subtype = PDFStremObj.Get(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.SUBTYPE);

                        if ((subtype != null) && subtype.ToString() == iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.IMAGE.ToString())
                       // if ((subtype != null) && subtype.ToString() == iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfName.CCITTFAXDECODE.ToString())
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((iTextSharp.text.pdf.PRStream)PDFStremObj);

                            if ((bytes != null))
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    System.IO.MemoryStream MS = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);

                                    MS.Position = 0;
                                    System.Drawing.Image ImgPDF = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS);

                                    ImgList.Add(ImgPDF);

                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Exception in extract: " + e);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                PDFReaderObj.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return ImgList;
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the code to extract the images as well? That way it might be clearer why you are having difficulty merging these two together.

Comment: @ArnoudvanBokkem code added now for extraction also.

Comment: If you understand Java code, [this iText/Java solution of a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28087521/1729265) might show you how to proceed.