# Get text preceding image in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

What I'm trying to do is extract the image associated with some text in a PDF file. For instance, a PDF would have a photo of the front of a house. Just above the photo, there would be a caption which reads "Front View". I want the program to search the PDF for the text "Front View" and extract the photo that follows it.

I've looked iTextSharp, PDFsharp, and other utilities, but all of them treat the text in a PDF and the images separately. There doesn't seem to be any way to figure out that this line of text comes before that image.

We use iTextSharp for manipulating PDFs. I've written a method in C# that will extract an image given a page number, the number of the image on the page, and the image type. For instance, I can extract the 2nd jpeg on page 3. Here is the code for that. What I would like is to be able to search for a line of text in the file and then extract the image that follows that line of text.

```
public class ImageExtractor : IRenderListener
{
    int _currentPage = 1;
    int _imageCount = 0;
    int _index = 0;
    int _count = 0;
    readonly string _outputFilePrefix;
    readonly string _outputFolder;
    readonly bool _overwriteExistingFiles;
    string[] _fileTypes;

    public ImageExtractor(string outputFilePrefix, string outputFolder, bool overwriteExistingFiles, string[] fileTypes, int index)
    {
        _outputFilePrefix = outputFilePrefix;
        _outputFolder = outputFolder;
        _overwriteExistingFiles = overwriteExistingFiles;
        _fileTypes = fileTypes;
        _index = index;
    }

    public static int ExtractImageByIndex(string pdfPath, string outputFilePrefix, string outputFolder, bool overwriteExistingFiles, int pageNumber, int index, string[] fileTypes = null)
    {
        // Handle setting of any default values
        outputFilePrefix = outputFilePrefix ?? System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pdfPath);
        outputFolder = String.IsNullOrEmpty(outputFolder) ? System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(pdfPath) : outputFolder;

        var instance = new ImageExtractor(outputFilePrefix, outputFolder, overwriteExistingFiles, fileTypes, index);
        instance._currentPage = pageNumber;

        using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
        {
            if (pdfReader.NumberOfPages == 0)
                return 0;

            if (pdfReader.IsEncrypted())
                throw new ApplicationException(pdfPath + " is encrypted.");

            var pdfParser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);

            pdfParser.ProcessContent(instance._currentPage, instance);
        }

        return instance._imageCount;
    }

    public void BeginTextBlock() { }
    public void EndTextBlock() { }
    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) { }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        // If _index is greater than 0, we're looking for a specific image. If _count is
        // equal to _index, we've already found it, so don't go any farther.
        if (_index > 0 && _count == _index)
            return;

        var imageObject = renderInfo.GetImage();

        var imageFileName = "";

        if (_fileTypes != null)
        {
            var type = imageObject.GetFileType().ToLower();
            var flag = false;
            foreach (var t in _fileTypes)
            {
                if (t.ToLower() == type)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
                imageFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.{3}", _outputFilePrefix, _currentPage, _imageCount, imageObject.GetFileType());
        }
        else
        {
            imageFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}.{3}", _outputFilePrefix, _currentPage, _imageCount, imageObject.GetFileType());
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageFileName))
        {
            // If _index is 0, multiple images may be extracted. If _index is greater than 0,
            // RenderImage will increment count every time it finds an image that matches the
            // file type and will only extract the image if count equals index.
            if (_index > 0)
            {
                _count++;
                if (_count != _index)
                    return;
            }

            var imagePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_outputFolder, imageFileName);

            if (_overwriteExistingFiles || !File.Exists(imagePath))
            {
                var imageRawBytes = imageObject.GetImageAsBytes();

                File.WriteAllBytes(imagePath, imageRawBytes);

            }

            // Subtle: Always increment even if file is not written. This ensures consistency should only some
            //   of a PDF file's images actually exist.
            _imageCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: PDF files may or may not treat images and text “separately”, we'd need to see your PDFs to tell. “the line of text that immediately precedes an image” can be interpreted in many ways; you'll have to give a definition of what you mean. Depending on these there are many different approaches, different for each type of software, and you haven't told us what you “looked” at. Hopelessly vague.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28087521/1729265) shows how to extract text and images including tags in the text representing positions of images in the text flow. The solution is for itext in java and, therefore, should be easy to port to itextsharp in c#.

Comment: I've uploaded some code I wrote that extracts an image based on its page number and it's index on the page. That is, you can tell it to get the 2nd image on the 2nd page. I'm not sure how to upload a sample pdf. Do I need a minimum reputation for that or something? Thanks, mkl, for the "This answer" link. I'll take a look at that and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in a comment, this is very similar to the topic of the question [Extraction of images present inside a paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28042248/1729265) with the main difference that in the context of that question iText for Java was used instead of iTextSharp for .Net.

A port of the Java `SimpleMixedExtractionStrategy` from that question might look like this:

```
public class SimpleMixedExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    FieldInfo field = typeof(LocationTextExtractionStrategy).GetField("locationalResult", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    LineSegment UNIT_LINE = new LineSegment(new Vector(0, 0, 1), new Vector(1, 0, 1));
    String outputPath;
    String name;
    int counter = 0;

    public SimpleMixedExtractionStrategy(String outputPath, String name)
    {
        this.outputPath = outputPath;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        PdfImageObject image = renderInfo.GetImage();
        if (image == null) return;
        int number = counter++;
        String filename = name + "-" + number + "." + image.GetFileType();
        File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath + filename, image.GetImageAsBytes());

        LineSegment segment = UNIT_LINE.TransformBy(renderInfo.GetImageCTM());
        TextChunk location = new TextChunk("[" + filename + "]", segment.GetStartPoint(), segment.GetEndPoint(), 0f);

        List<TextChunk> locationalResult = (List<TextChunk>)field.GetValue(this);
        locationalResult.Add(location);
    }
}
```

*Just like in the Java implementation, it is necessary to use reflection to access the `private List<TextChunk> locationalResult` in `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`. If the use of reflection is not allowed in your project, you can copy the whole source of `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to an own class and apply the changes to the copy.*

You might use it like this:

```
String sourceFile = @"SOURCE.pdf";
String imagePath = @"extract\";
String imageBaseName = "SOURCE-";
Directory.CreateDirectory(imagePath);

using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(sourceFile))
{
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);
    for (var i = 1; i <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        SimpleMixedExtractionStrategy listener = new SimpleMixedExtractionStrategy(imagePath, imageBaseName + i);
        parser.ProcessContent(i, listener);
        String text = listener.GetResultantText();
        Console.Write("Text of page {0}:\n---\n{1}\n\n", i, text);
    }
}
```

For the example file from the referred-to question

[image]

the output is:

```
Text of page 1:
---
Getting Started with Vaadin
• A version of Book of Vaadin that you can browse in the Eclipse Help system.
You can install the plugin as follows:
1. Start Eclipse.
2. Select Help   Software Updates....
3. Select the Available Software tab.
4. Add the Vaadin plugin update site by clicking Add Site....
[book-of-vaadin-page14-1-0.png]
Enter the URL of the Vaadin Update Site: http://vaadin.com/eclipse and click OK. The
Vaadin site should now appear in the Software Updates window.
5. Select all the Vaadin plugins in the tree.
[book-of-vaadin-page14-1-1.png]
Finally, click Install.
Detailed and up-to-date installation instructions for the Eclipse plugin can be found at http://vaad-
in.com/eclipse.
Updating the Vaadin Plugin
If you have automatic updates enabled in Eclipse (see Window   Preferences   Install/Update
  Automatic Updates), the Vaadin plugin will be updated automatically along with other plugins.
Otherwise, you can update the Vaadin plugin (there are actually multiple plugins) manually as
follows:
1. Select Help   Software Updates..., the Software Updates and Add-ons window will
open.
2. Select the Installed Software tab.
14 Vaadin Plugin for Eclipse
```

Thus, for your task

> What I would like is to be able to search for a line of text in the file and then extract the image that follows that line of text.

simply search for that *line of text* in the output string above and look for the next line containing an image file name in square brackets.

(If your PDF also uses square brackets, you can envelop the file name in other delimiters in the `SimpleMixedExtractionStrategy`, e.g. some characters from a Unicode private use area.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Before I saw your post, I managed to come up with a solution which seems to work for me. I'll post that solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found. The original code contains a lot of stuff that's not directly related to the question, so I simplified it for the post.

```
public class ImageExtractor : IRenderListener
{
    private string caption;
    private bool _captionFound;
    private string _outputFolder;

    ....
    ....

    public void BeginTextBlock() { }

    public void EndTextBlock() { }

    public void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        // If this line of text contains the caption, set _captionFound to true
        if (renderInfo.GetText().Contains(_caption))
            _captionFound = true;
    }

    public void RenderImage(ImageRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        // Skip the image if _captionFound is false
        if (!_captionFound)
            return;

        // _captionFound is true, so extract the image

        // Code to extract image

        // Set _captionFound back to false, so that only the first image found is
        // extracted.
        _captionFound = false;

    }

    public static int ExtractImageByCaption(string caption, string pdfPath, string outputFolder, string outputFolder, bool overwriteExistingFiles, string[] fileTypes = null)
    {
        var instance = new ImageExtractor(outputFilePrefix, outputFolder, overwriteExistingFiles, fileTypes, 0);

        instance._caption = caption;
        instance._outputFolder = outputFolder;

        using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfPath))
        {
            if (pdfReader.IsEncrypted())
                throw new ApplicationException(pdfPath + " is encrypted.");

            var pdfParser = new PdfReaderContentParser(pdfReader);

            while (instance._currentPage <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages)
            {
                pdfParser.ProcessContent(instance._currentPage, instance);

                instance._currentPage++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution relies on two conditions: **a** the content stream must be drawn in reading order, in particular the image captions right before the images, and **b** the captions must be drawn in a single instruction. Neither of these conditions are automatically true, the pdf format allows content to be drawn in arbitrary order and text lines might be drawn piece-wise. Thus, there may be a number of pdfs this approach works with, but there also are numerous pdfs it won't work with.

Comment: The image captions don't have to be right before the image. The code extracts the first image it finds after it finds the caption. Otherwise, I agree with you. The pdfs we are using this on come in a standard format, so it should work for them. I'm not claiming this will work for every type of pdf.

Comment: *"The image captions don't have to be right before the image."* - ok, to be more exact, first the caption, then the image must be drawn; and between caption and associated image no other images must be drawn. (There are PDF producers that draw all images at the beginning or at the end, so even those conditions cannot be taken for sure.)